# How to count occurrence of items in a list in Python?

Tags: python

lets say:

```
 a = [1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]
```

b is dict

I want b as dict which represents number of occurrence of items in a:
I want **jinja2** template that create output as below.

Output of b should be,  ( key - itemName, Value - corresponding item occurrence in list)

```
1 : 2  
2 : 2  
3 : 4  
4 : 4
```

Is it possible to do via jinja2 template - i have jinja engine which renders some output i want to add this kind of stuff in template.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain how your post relates to `jinja2`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `collection.Counter` to perform these operations efficiently:

```py
from collections import Counter
a = [1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4] 
result = dict(Counter(a)) # {1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 4, 4: 4}

for index, value in result.items():
    print(str(index) + " : " + str(value))
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
count_dict = {i:a.count(i) for i in set(a)}
```

is that what you asked for?

Comment: This works, but will lose the order of the list elements.

Answer (score -1):

You can also do this:

```
a = [1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4] 
frequency = {}
for i  in range(len(a)):
    frequency[a[i]] = a.count(a[i])
print(frequency)
```